# How to stop crashing JLabels

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, jlabel

I am doing a little GUI application to simulate a Swimming competition. I have a separate GUI for swimming pool and for the score board, where swimmers are moved by 5 threads and by the time they reach the touch pad I've coded to display that time in the score board.

Problem is whenever those time showing Labels in the score board are updated swimmers suddenly move back to the starting position(not a continuous movement just vanishing and appearing at the starting point) without staying near the touch pad. But this is working if the labels are not updated.

Here is the image of the GUI.
[image]

This is not the full code but this is the code segment responsible for the movement of the swimmers and the updating the time labels when swimmer finishes the length.

```
private final Map<Swimmer, JLabel> mapLaneTime = new HashMap<>();

private void startTheGame(final String swimmingStyle) {

    final ArrayList<Swimmer> listSwimmer = 
                               new ArrayList<>  (mapSwimmers.keySet());

    for (int i = 0; i < mapSwimmers.size(); i++) {
        final Swimmer swmr = listSwimmer.get(i);

        // set up the intial position of the JLabel to the swimmer
        swmr.setCurrentPosition(mapSwimmers.get(swmr).getX());               
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    swmr.slowDown();
                    JLabel lblSwmr = mapSwimmers.get(swmr);
                    swmr.doSwimmingStyle(swimmingStyle);

                    int startPosition = swmr.getCurrentPosition();

                    while ((swmr.getCurrentPosition()
                            != swmr.getSwimLane().getLength()
                            + startPosition)) {

                        lblSwmr.setLocation(swmr.doLegMovements(),
                                lblSwmr.getY());

                        swmr.doHandMovements();
                        swmr.speedUp();
                    }
// time takes for the swimmer to touch the touch pad 
                    double time = swmr.touchTheTouchPad(swimmingEvent);


/** problem comes when the below line is present it is the way to set text 
 ** to the label if this is not here swimmers properly end the length
 ** without appearing at the starting position when ever they finish the 
 ** length 
 **/                   
                    mapLaneTime.get(swmr).setText(time + "");

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    swmr.giveUp();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

There are no problems with the thread at all. Don't care about the other methods. There is nothing wrong with the other implementations.

I'm sorry I forgot to mention swmr.giveUP() is method that releases the lock (Lock lock = new ReentrantLock()). The lock is defined in the Swimmer class. There is another thread in the swimmer class to update the position of the Swimmer which uses the same lock

here is the complete code for Swimmer class , ScoreBoard class

Swimmer class (This is a abstract class which has a two child classes    MaleSwimmer and FemaleSwimmer)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public abstract class Swimmer extends Person {

    private final String gender;            // gender of the Swimmer                               
    private final String costumeColor;       //color of the costume                                                        
    private final int personalBest;
    private volatile int currentPosition;
    private SwimLane swimLane;
    private final Lock lock;                // lock for the thread                                              
    private final Condition condition;

    protected Swimmer(String name, String gender, String costumeColor) {
        super(name);
        this.gender = gender;
        this.costumeColor = costumeColor;

        Random random = new Random();
        this.personalBest = random.nextInt(20) + 8;
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        condition = lock.newCondition();
    }

    public SwimLane getSwimLane() {
        return this.swimLane;
    }

/**
 * @return the color of the swimming costume
 */
protected String getDressColor() {
    return this.costumeColor;
}

/**
 * perform hand movements
 */
protected void doHandMovements() {
    this.condition.signalAll();
}

/**
 * perform leg movements
 *
 * @return
 */
protected int doLegMovements() {
    return this.currentPosition;
}

/**
 * perform Butterfly stroke
 *
 * @param sleepTime
 */
protected abstract void doButterflyStroke(int sleepTime);

/**
 * perform Backstroke
 *
 * @param sleepTime
 */
protected abstract void doBackStroke(int sleepTime);

/**
 * perform Breaststroke
 *
 * @param sleepTime
 */
protected abstract void doBreastStroke(int sleepTime);

/**
 * perform Freestyle
 *
 * @param sleepTime
 */
protected abstract void doFreeStyle(int sleepTime);

public void doSwimmingStyle(String style) {
    switch (style) {

        case "Freestyle":
            doFreeStyle(personalBest);
            break;

        case "Backstroke":
            doBackStroke(personalBest);
            break;

        case "Butterfly Stroke":
            doButterflyStroke(personalBest);
            break;

        case "Breaststroke":
            doBreastStroke(personalBest);
            break;
    }
    this.swimLane.getTouchPad().startTimer();                               // start the timer when swimmer starts to swim
}

void updatePosition(int sleepTime, double factor) {
    final int swimTime = (int) (sleepTime * factor);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                lock.lock();                                                // lock the thread
                int endPosition = currentPosition + swimLane.getLength();   // length of the lane from staring to end

                while (currentPosition <= endPosition) {
                    currentPosition++;
                    Thread.sleep(swimTime);
                    condition.signal();
                    condition.await();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();                                              // give up the lock from the thread
            }

        }
    }).start();
}

public int getPersonalBest() {
    return this.personalBest;
}

public void setCurrentPosition(int currentPosition) {
    this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return this.currentPosition;
}

public void setSwimLane(SwimLane swimLane) {
    this.swimLane = swimLane;
}

/**
 * When swimmer finish the event swimmer should touch the touch pad. This
 * method achieve that task
 *
 * @param swimmingEvent
 * @return swimmer's finishing time
 */
public double touchTheTouchPad(SwimmingEvent swimmingEvent) {
    return this.swimLane.getTouchPad().notifyScoreBoard(this,      
    swimmingEvent);
}

public void slowDown() throws InterruptedException {
    this.lock.lock();
}

public void speedUp() throws InterruptedException {
    this.condition.awaitNanos(500);

}

public void giveUp() {
    this.lock.unlock();
}
```

}

class ScoreBoard

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class ScoreBoard implements Serializable {

Queue<Double> time;
Queue<Swimmer> swimmers;
Map<Swimmer, Double> finalResults;

private int numberOfRows;
private final Lock lock;
private final Condition condition;

public ScoreBoard() {
    time = new LinkedList<>();
    swimmers = new LinkedList<>();
    finalResults = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    lock = new ReentrantLock();
    condition = lock.newCondition();
}

/**
 * This method will add swimmer and timeTaken to the list
 *
 * @param swimmer swimmer who completed the event
 * @param timeTaken time took for swimmer to complete the event
 */
public void updateList(Swimmer swimmer, double timeTaken) {

    time.add(timeTaken);
    swimmers.add(swimmer);

}

/**
 * This method will start the process of the Score Board
 */
public void powerUp() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
// swimmer will take more than 4s to complete a game
                Thread.sleep(4000);                                            
                lock.lock();                                                    
                while (swimmers.size() != numberOfRows) {                                      
// wait this thread untill this is awoken
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                comapreTimes();
                condition.signal();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }

        }

    }).start();
}

/**
 * This method will set the number of rows in Score Board
 *
 * @param numberOfRows number of rows that should be in Score Board
 */
public void setNumberOfRows(int numberOfRows) {
    this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
}

/**
 * This method will pass the lock to the thread inside the powerUp method
 */
public void lockTheScoreBoard() {
    this.lock.lock();
}

public void unlockTheScoreBoard() {
    this.lock.unlock();
}

public void awaitScoreBoard() throws InterruptedException {
    this.condition.await();
}

void comapreTimes() {
    for (Swimmer s : swimmers) {
        this.finalResults.put(s, time.poll());
        // need to do something more in here
    }
}

public Map<Swimmer, Double> getFinalResults() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return this.finalResults;
}
```

}

I tried to update JLabels using SwingWorker thread also, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Update your labels in Swing Thread. Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: Your panel is using a Layout manager, which is been cause to update when you call setText. My suggestion is, don't use components for this kind of thing, instead use custom painting

Comment: You have a bug in your code, it is not here. We need the full code, does you have any stack trace of exception?

Comment: Also, your call to swmr.giveUp(); should be called only when there is InterruptedException, right?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki  There is nothing wrong with the code as I mentioned in the problem this is only happens if the mapLaneTime.get(swmr).setText(time + ""); code line is present. If not all swimmers are going to stop near the touch pads

Comment: @Alexey using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() gives the same result

Comment: Post your entire code, there is nothing we can help with the code you have posted, the probelm is related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  swmr.giveUp(); should be moved from finally to the section executed for InterruptedExcveption.

Why every simmer is giving up? Only loosers should.

Check if that will fix it. Maybe it is the case.

You know, I think there is no problem with setting the text of JLabel, it just forces to redraw the window, so meybe it is why you see all your swimmers at the beginnig, does swmr.giveUp(); reset their positions to start?

If this is the case, then it is why you see all of them at the beginnig after setting a JLabel text, because they have this position already, but if you don't redraw you will not see their new positions.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention swmr.giveUP() is method that releases the lock (Lock lock = new ReentrantLock()). The lock is defined in the Swimmer class. There is another thread in the swimmer class to update the position of the Swimmer.

Comment: I tried moving the swmr.giveUP() into the section of InterruptedException but no change same problem.

Comment: do you have any exception?

Comment: No exceptions at all for this. Only thing is this. if that line is not there( mapLaneTime.get(swmr).setText(time + ""); ) all the swimmers are going to stop near the touch pads without any exceptions